# Codename one Radio Buttons in a ButtonGroup

Tags: radio-button, codenameone

@Shai According to the image below got from CleanMordern Project.
how can I style my radio buttons using CSS to look exactly as Shai did his,
and also  make actions on each button to show different container when pressed 
[image]

```
ButtonGroup barGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    RadioButton all = RadioButton.createToggle("All", barGroup);
    all.setUIID("SelectBar");
    RadioButton featured = RadioButton.createToggle("Featured", barGroup);
    featured.setUIID("SelectBar");
    RadioButton popular = RadioButton.createToggle("Popular", barGroup);
    popular.setUIID("SelectBar");
    RadioButton myFavorite = RadioButton.createToggle("My Favorites", barGroup);
    myFavorite.setUIID("SelectBar");
    Label arrow = new Label(res.getImage("news-tab-down-arrow.png"), "Container");

    add(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(
            GridLayout.encloseIn(4, all, featured, popular, myFavorite),
            FlowLayout.encloseBottom(arrow)
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the theme file in the designer tool and just copy the styling from there. I implemented this using image backgrounds to keep some pixels free for the arrow on the bottom.

If you look at the theme you will see I just placed a background image that's solid red on top and has a white bottom. Then I have a separate "arrow" image which is animated with the code to the selected button on every click. Everything else is just colors and fonts which is trivial.

Comment: Thank you Shai i have  Achievd the first Step ,now how do i set action to each Button to call its own container like the way tabs work

Comment: addActionListener then use a Container.replace() to change the content of the main container. You can do that with a transition animation. You can even use a regular tabs component below with the tabs hidden

Comment: am failing to use this -curent.replace(origin, curent, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true, 200)); please is there an example that I can follow

Comment: It should be `origin.getParent().replace(origin, curent, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true, 200));` there are examples of everything in the developer guide, javadocs and demos

Comment: Thank you; what is confusing me is the "origin" and the "current"

Comment: origin = the container that is currently displayed in the parent layout. So you get its parent container and within that parent replace it with the new current container. To make it look nice you add an animation to that simple replacement.